# Autodesk Forge Data Management - Object Id vs Object Name vs Object Key

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am attempting to write some additional functionality to support an already-working application that uses the Data Management, Model Derivative, and Viewer APIs. It does not create versions of files in a Project, because that functionality did not exist when it was written.

Right now we support uploading a file which uploads it to Forge. We store the response from Forge and use that again to get the Viewer working.

The PUT buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName API takes an Object Name for an "upload new version" functionality.

However, the API returns ObjectId, ObjectKey, and ObjectUrn, none of which work for ObjectName in a round trip (I always get 412), and I cannot seem to get anything but 404's from the Get Object API.

I'm using the C# Library in NuGet.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the file was deleted automatically due to the bucket policy. Please check [OSS Retention Policy](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/) here. If your bucket policy is either [Transient](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/#transient) or [Temporary](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/#temporary), your uploaded files will be removed by the preconfigured time.

In addition, to download an object via [forge-api-dotnet-client](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/ObjectsApi.md#getobject)#[GetObject](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/ObjectsApi.md#getobject), the object name is the same value as you passed to [UploadObject](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/docs/ObjectsApi.md#uploadobject). In the response payload, you can see it here:

```
{
  "bucketKey" : "mybucket",
  "objectId" : "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:mybucket/example.txt",
  "objectKey" : "example.txt",                                   //!<<<< The object name
  "sha1" : "cc2071e3c3a0e95ec68c599ccac6f8caa012677e",
  "size" : 525,
  "contentType" : "text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
  "location" : "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/mybucket/objects/example.txt"
}
```

Comment: Bucket was almost certainly set to persistent. How do I check? It's a very old bucket

Comment: Call https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-details-GET/ to check bucket details